# SharePoint Online Mobile View

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile-view

I am setting up a new Intranet on O365 SharePoint Online and I am trying to make it work with a Mobile phone (Android & Iphone).  I have activated Mobile View.

However when I go to the Browser it looks identical to the desktop view...

I want this to operate like other web sites so when on a mobile it fits on one horizotnal screen but you have to scroll down further to see everything.

Comment: In Android's chrome browser, you will one checkbox "Desktop site". Please try to uncheck that option and refresh your page, I think it would then display mobile view.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this does not work unless you were supposed to develop a mobile view and if so how???

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate **Mobile Browser View** feature then re-activate the feature again.

And also clear the cache of your phone browser.

Then test again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Modern or a Classic site?  Modern sites should be mobile responsive out of the box, Classic sites require some tweaking in the site branding to get them to be responsive.